# Are views harmful for performance in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, view

The following is an excerpt from a book about db design (Beginning Database Design ISBN: 0-7645-7490-6):

> The danger with using views is filtering a query against a view,
>   expecting to read a very small portion of a very large table. Any filtering should be done within
>   the view because any filtering against the view itself is applied after the query in the view has
>   completed execution. Views are typically useful for speeding up the development process but
>   in the long run can completely kill database performance.

The following is an excerpt from PostgreSQL 9.5 Documentation:

> Making liberal use of views is a key aspect of good SQL database design. Views allow you to encapsulate
>   the details of the structure of your tables, which might change as your application evolves,
>   behind consistent interfaces.

The two sources seem to contradict each other ("do not design with views" vs. "do design with views").

However, in PG views are implemented using the rule system.  So, possibly (and this is my question) any filtering against the view is rewritten as a filter within the view, resulting in a single query execution against the underlying tables.

Is my interpretation correct and PG combines WHERE clauses into and out of the view?  Or does it run them separately, one after another?  Any short, self contained, correct (compilable), examples?

Comment: I think the question is not right because both sources are not talking about the same thing. The first one is related to query from a view and AFTER apply a filter: `SELECT * FROM my_view WHERE my_column = 'blablabla';`.While the second is about using views to make your data model transparent to the application that uses it. The first sources points you to include the filter `WHERE my_column = 'blablabla'`inside the view definition, as this result in a better execution plan.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The book is wrong.

Selecting from a view is **exactly** as fast or slow as running the underlying SQL statement – you can easily check that using `explain analyze`.

The Postgres optimizer (and the optimizer for many other modern DBMSes) will be able to push down predicates on the view into the actual view statement – provided this is a simple statement (again, this can be verified using `explain analyze`).

The "bad reputation" regarding performance stems – I think – from when you overuse views and start building views that use views that use views. Very often that results in statements that do too much compared to a statement that was hand-tailored without the views e.g. because some intermediate tables wouldn't be needed. In almost all cases the optimizer is not smart enough to remove those unneeded tables/joins or to push down predicates over multiple levels of views (this is true for other DBMSes as well).

Comment: Given some of the counter-answers proposed, you may want to expound a bit on what is a *simple statement*.

Comment: Can you explain how to use the `explain analyze` statement?

Comment: @DustinMichels: have a look at the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html

Comment: A note on "In almost all cases the optimizer is not smart enough to remove those unneeded tables/joins" this seems to be related to whether the join conditions in the view match any indices on the right table

Comment: Explain analyze result is different if use like 'XXX%' in view vs use 'XXX%' in table

Answer (score 29):

To give you an **example** of what [@a_horse explained](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/151220/3684):

Postgres implements the information schema, which consists of (sometimes complex) ***views*** providing information about DB objects in standardized form. This is convenient and reliable - and can be substantially more expensive than accessing the Postgres catalog tables directly.

Very simple example, to get all visible columns of a table
... from the information schema:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 'big'
AND    table_schema = 'public';
```

... from the system catalog:

```
SELECT attname
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'public.big'::regclass
AND    attnum > 0
AND    NOT attisdropped;
```

Compare query plans and execution time for both with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

- The first query is based on the view `information_schema.columns`, which joins to multiple tables we do not need for this at all.
- The second query only scans the *one* table `pg_catalog.pg_attribute`, hence much faster. (But the first query still only needs a few ms in common DBs.)

Details:

- [Query to return output column names and data types of a query, table or view](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75015/query-to-return-output-column-names-and-data-types-of-a-query-table-or-view/75124#75124)

Answer (score 17):

EDIT:

With apologies, I need to retract my assertion that the accepted answer is not always correct - it states that the view is always identical to the same thing written as a subquery.  I think that's indisputable, and I think I now know what's going on in my case.

I now also think there's a better answer to the original question.

The original question is about whether it should be guiding practice to use views (as opposed to, for example, repeating SQL in routines which may need to be maintained twice or more).

My answer would be "not if your query uses window functions or anything else which causes the optimiser to treat the query differently when it becomes a subquery, because the very act of creating the subquery (whether represented as a view or not) may degrade performance if you are filtering with parameters at runtime.

The complexity of my window function is unnecessary.  The explain plan for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ts.train_service_key,
            pc.assembly_key,
            count(*) OVER 
              (PARTITION BY ts.train_service_key) AS train_records
FROM staging.train_service ts
   JOIN staging.portion_consist pc 
     USING (ds_code, train_service_key)
WHERE assembly_key = '185132';
```

is much less costly than for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ts.train_service_key,
            pc.assembly_key,
            count(*) OVER
              (PARTITION BY ts.train_service_key) AS train_records
FROM staging.train_service ts
   JOIN staging.portion_consist pc
     USING (ds_code, train_service_key)) AS query
WHERE assembly_key = '185132';
```

Hope that's a bit more specific and helpful.

In my recent experience (causing me to find this question), the accepted answer above isn't correct under all circumsances.  I have a relatively simple query that includes a window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ts.train_service_key,
                pc.assembly_key,
                dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ts.train_service_key
                ORDER BY pc.through_idx DESC, pc.first_portion ASC,
               ((CASE WHEN (NOT ts.primary_direction)
                 THEN '-1' :: INTEGER
                 ELSE 1
                 END) * pc.first_seq)) AS coach_block_idx
FROM (staging.train_service ts
JOIN staging.portion_consist pc USING (ds_code, train_service_key))
```

If I add this filter:

```
where assembly_key = '185132'
```

The explain plan I get is as follows:

```
QUERY PLAN
Unique  (cost=11562.66..11568.77 rows=814 width=43)
  ->  Sort  (cost=11562.66..11564.70 rows=814 width=43)
    Sort Key: ts.train_service_key, (dense_rank() OVER (?))
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=11500.92..11523.31 rows=814 width=43)
          ->  Sort  (cost=11500.92..11502.96 rows=814 width=35)
                Sort Key: ts.train_service_key, pc.through_idx DESC, pc.first_portion, ((CASE WHEN (NOT ts.primary_direction) THEN '-1'::integer ELSE 1 END * pc.first_seq))
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=20.39..11461.57 rows=814 width=35)
                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on portion_consist pc  (cost=19.97..3370.39 rows=973 width=38)
                            Recheck Cond: (assembly_key = '185132'::text)
                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on portion_consist_assembly_key_index  (cost=0.00..19.72 rows=973 width=0)
                                  Index Cond: (assembly_key = '185132'::text)
                      ->  Index Scan using train_service_pk on train_service ts  (cost=0.43..8.30 rows=1 width=21)
                            Index Cond: ((ds_code = pc.ds_code) AND (train_service_key = pc.train_service_key))
```

This is using the primary key index on the train service table and a non-unique index on the portion_consist table.  It executes in 90ms.

I created a view (pasting it here to be absolutely clear but it's literally the query in a view):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW staging.v_unit_coach_block AS
SELECT DISTINCT ts.train_service_key,
            pc.assembly_key,
            dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ts.train_service_key
              ORDER BY pc.through_idx DESC, pc.first_portion ASC, (
                (CASE
              WHEN (NOT ts.primary_direction)
                THEN '-1' :: INTEGER
              ELSE 1
              END) * pc.first_seq)) AS coach_block_idx
 FROM (staging.train_service ts
  JOIN staging.portion_consist pc USING (ds_code, train_service_key))
```

When I query this view with the identical filter:

```
select * from staging.v_unit_coach_block
where assembly_key = '185132';
```

This is the explain plan:

```
QUERY PLAN
Subquery Scan on v_unit_coach_block  (cost=494217.13..508955.10     rows=3275 width=31)
Filter: (v_unit_coach_block.assembly_key = '185132'::text)
 ->  Unique  (cost=494217.13..500767.34 rows=655021 width=43)
    ->  Sort  (cost=494217.13..495854.68 rows=655021 width=43)
          Sort Key: ts.train_service_key, pc.assembly_key, (dense_rank() OVER (?))
          ->  WindowAgg  (cost=392772.16..410785.23 rows=655021 width=43)
                ->  Sort  (cost=392772.16..394409.71 rows=655021 width=35)
                      Sort Key: ts.train_service_key, pc.through_idx DESC, pc.first_portion, ((CASE WHEN (NOT ts.primary_direction) THEN '-1'::integer ELSE 1 END * pc.first_seq))
                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=89947.40..311580.26 rows=655021 width=35)
                            Hash Cond: ((pc.ds_code = ts.ds_code) AND (pc.train_service_key = ts.train_service_key))
                            ->  Seq Scan on portion_consist pc  (cost=0.00..39867.86 rows=782786 width=38)
                            ->  Hash  (cost=65935.36..65935.36 rows=1151136 width=21)
                                  ->  Seq Scan on train_service ts  (cost=0.00..65935.36 rows=1151136 width=21)
```

This is doing full scans on both tables and takes 17s.

Until I came across this I have been liberally using views with PostgreSQL (having understood the widely-held views expressed in the accepted answer).  I'd specifically avoid using views if I need pre-aggregate filtering, for which I'd use set-returning functions.

I'm also aware that CTEs in PostgreSQL are strictly evaluated separately, by design, so I don't use them in the same way I would with SQL Server, for example, where they seem to be optimised as subqueries.

My answer, therefore, is, there are instances in which views do not perform exactly as the query upon which they are based, so caution is advised.  I am using Amazon Aurora based on PostgreSQL 9.6.6.

Comment: Note the caveat in [the other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/151220/116653) - "*provided this is a simple statement*".

Comment: As a side note, `CASE
              WHEN (NOT ts.primary_direction)
                THEN '-1' :: INTEGER
              ELSE 1
              END` will needless make the query slower than need be you're better off writing two more conditionals in the order.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I struggled with this for a while.  Just found it is marginally faster to pull the CASE out one level: `CASE
                  WHEN (NOT ts.primary_direction)
                          THEN dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ts.train_service_key
                  ORDER BY pc.through_idx DESC, pc.first_portion ASC, pc.first_seq DESC)
                  ELSE dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ts.train_service_key
                ORDER BY pc.through_idx DESC, pc.first_portion ASC, pc.first_seq ASC)
                END AS coach_block_idx`

Comment: That's not a good idea either.. you've got a few problems here. I mean the big one is that your view doesn't really make sense and it does different things because of your use of `dense_rank()` so it's not really a performance issue.

Comment: For example, watch this... `SELECT * FROM (SELECT x, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY x) FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM generate_series(1,10)) AS t(x)) AS t WHERE x=2;` vs `SELECT x, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY x) FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM generate_series(1,10)) AS t(x) WHERE x =2;` **run both of those queries and try to grok the result** when it makes sense you'll understand why it's not really the views fault in this case.

Comment: @EvanCarroll your comment prompted me to get there myself (hence my edited answer).  Thank you.

Comment: @enjayaitch you say "The complexity of my window function is unnecessary" but your new *simplified* one suffers the same problem.

Comment: @enjayaitch try this, `SELECT x, count(*) OVER (ORDER BY x) FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM generate_series(1,10)) AS t(x) WHERE x =2;` vs `SELECT * FROM (SELECT x, count(*) OVER (ORDER BY x) FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM generate_series(1,10)) AS t(x)) AS t WHERE x=2;`

Comment: @EvanCarroll aren't we saying the same thing?  "Unnecessary" to demonstrate the difference between a query using a window function with a filter and the same query as a subquery with a filter in the outer query?  I could have used your examples instead of mine in the edited answer?

Answer (score 7):

(I am a huge fan of views, but you have to be very careful with PG here and **I would like to encourage everybody to use views generally also in PG** for better understandability and maintainability of queries/code)

Actually and sadly (WARNING:) **using views in Postgres caused us real problems and badly decreased our performance depending on the features we were using inside of it :-(** (at least with v10.1 / upd: regarding v12 see below).
(This would be not so with other modern DB systems like Oracle.)

> So, possibly (and this is my question) any filtering against the view ... resulting in a single query execution against the underlying tables.

(Depending on what you exactly mean - no - intermediate temp tables may be materialized that you may not want to be or where predicates are not pushed down on ...)

I know at least two major "features", that **let us down** in the middle of **migrations from Oracle to Postgres** so we had to abandon PG in a project:

- **CTEs** (`with`-clause subqueries / [common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)) are (usually) useful for structuring more complex queries (even in smaller applications), but in PG are by design implemented as **"hidden" optimizer** hints (generating e.g. non-indexed temp tables) and thus **violate** the (for me and a lot of others important) **concept of declarative SQL** ([Oracle docu](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2077142)) (*upd 2020-08-02*: with [PG v12+](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) these sample query plans should be the same by now) : e.g.

  - simple query:

    ```
        explain

          select * from pg_indexes where indexname='pg_am_name_index'

        /* result: 

        Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=12.38..26.67 rows=1 width=260)
          ...
          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pg_class_relname_nsp_index  (cost=0.00..4.29 rows=2 width=0)
                                                 Index Cond: (relname = 'pg_am_name_index'::name)
          ...
        */
    ```
  - rewritten using some CTE:

    ```
        explain

          with 

          unfiltered as (
            select * from pg_indexes
          ) 

          select * from unfiltered where indexname='pg_am_name_index'

        /* result:

        CTE Scan on unfiltered  (cost=584.45..587.60 rows=1 width=288)
           Filter: (indexname = 'pg_am_name_index'::name)
           CTE unfiltered
             ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=230.08..584.45 rows=140 width=260)  
        ...
        */
    ```
  - further sources with discussions etc.: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/
- **window functions** with `over`-statements are [**potentially unusable**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237463/bad-optimization-planning-on-postgres-window-based-queries-partition-by-group#comment41339598_26237464)
  (typically used in views, e.g. as a source for reports based on more complex queries)

---

## `with`-clauses may work since v12

*update 2020-08-01*: looking at the [v12 `with` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) **in some or all *your* cases** there is a long-needed optimization now in place (but still likely not working if *window functions* are used there, as detailed just above):

> *However, if a WITH query is **non-recursive and side-effect-free (that
> is, it is a SELECT containing no volatile functions)** then it can be
> folded into the parent query, allowing joint optimization of the two
> query levels. **By default**, this happens **if the parent query references
> the WITH query just once**, but not if it references the WITH query more
> than once. You can override that decision by specifying **MATERIALIZED**
> to force separate calculation of the WITH query, or by specifying **NOT
> MATERIALIZED** to force it to be merged into the parent query. The
> latter choice risks duplicate computation of the WITH query, but it
> can still give a net savings if each usage of the WITH query needs
> only a small part of the WITH query's full output.*

## our workaround for the `with`-clauses (PG v10)

We will transform all the "inline views" to real views with a special prefix so they do not mess up the list/namespace of views and can easily be related to the original "outer view" :-/

---

## our solution for the window functions

We implemented it successfully using the Oracle database.

Comment: **[Discussion moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74553/discussion-between-ypercube-and-andreas-dietrich)**.

Comment: As someone lacking expertise, I was wondering if anyone can confirm my reading of this -- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html -- to indicate that the problem noted by Andreas has been resolved in PG12?

Comment: Dear @Wellspring, I just updated my answer to reflect the changes and thanks a lot or this important hint/feature! :) **There may be now a to-be-individually-checked chance, that your non-window-function-containing views/`with`-queries may be optimized**. **I would recommend some project architect at your side to check, how likely it is, that the "bad" cases would be used/necessary**, either (unconciously) by developers or desired/necessary in the future and **thus may lead to ugly workarounds, harming maintainability, performance, increasing risks and/or costs**.