# List all column names for multi-joined table

Tags: postgresql, join, query

I have a slightly more complicated join:

```sql
SELECT person.given_name, person.family_name, person.age, person.sex, person.state,
       person.zip, person.street, person.residential_number,
       c1.name as citizen_of_country,
       c2.name as hospitalization_country,
       c3.name as infection_country

FROM patients

    JOIN person on patients.person_id = person.id
    JOIN country c1 on person."citizenOf_country_id" = c1.id
    JOIN country c2 on patients.hospitalized_in_country_id = c2.id
    JOIN country c3 on patients.infected_in_country_id = c3.id;
```

.. and I'd like to somehow get the name of all columns in this new table. Based on some answers I found, I tried

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND [code];
```

Where [code] is the block above.. But it didn't work, giving the error "Subquery must return only one column". I'm new to databases so I'm not sure how to handle this correctly.

Comment: `information_schema` views contain metadata for database object, like tables and views. Your query is not a database object, so there isn't anything about it in the system catalog. You have written the query, so _you_ should already know the columns _you_ are retrieving. I suspect this is an example of an X-Y problem; can you describe the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: This is inside a method in Python utilizing the psycopg2 library. I want to return the data and also the column names for the data so it's easy for the other coder to work with and bind it to the GUI. So I assume I just have to return that manually for the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the information from yourcursor.description. Example:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("""SELECT person.given_name, ...""")

curs.description
```

You can find more info under metadata on [zetcode.com/python/psycopg2/](http://zetcode.com/python/psycopg2/)

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like to somehow get the name of all columns in this new table.

You can create a [temporary view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html), which registers the row type. Then query either the information schema like you tried or the system catalog `pg_attribute`:

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW tmp_v1 AS SELECT ...;  -- your query here

SELECT attname
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'pg_temp.tmp_v1'::regclass;
```

Returns the desired list of column names.

Catalog tables or information schema? See:

- [Query to return output column names and data types of a query, table or view](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75015/query-to-return-output-column-names-and-data-types-of-a-query-table-or-view/75124#75124)

The temporary view is only visible inside your current session and dropped at its end. (Or you can drop it manually.)

---

In **psql** you could use the meta-command `\gdesc`:

```
test=# SELECT 1 AS foo \gdesc
 Column |  Type
--------+---------
 foo    | integer
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

> `\gdesc`
>
> Shows the description (that is, the column names and data types) of
>   the result of the current query buffer. The query is not actually
>   executed; however, if it contains some type of syntax error, that
>   error will be reported in the normal way.
>
> If the current query buffer is empty, the most recently sent query is described instead.

So you can even execute a bare `\gdesc` after running the query to get a "table description" for the executed query.